# Broken Audio on Chromebook. Xbuntu

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, chromebook

I have dual-booted my Chromebook with Xubuntu 14.04 and have found that the sound is broken. I have tried everyhting that has been mentioned on the internet. I have restarted pulse, uninstalled it, unmuted sound in alsamixer, and nothing. The sound device shows up in settings as dummydevice. I have gotten everything else working except this, sound issue. I have a Samsung Series 3 ARM chromebook.

I believe that this might fix it, but my low skill level has kept me from copying the files.

1. copy some alsa support files from Chrome: `cp /media/root-a/usr/share/alsa/ucm/DAISY-I2S/HiFi.conf /usr/share/alsa/ucm/DAISY-I2S`
2. edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to add this line: `load-module module-alsa-sink device=sysdefault`

Any advice?

(UPDATE) I have inserted the HiFi.conf file into xubuntu and add the line to the default.pa. It nolonger has the name "dummy", but there is still no sound.

I have a copy of the "alsa-alsa-lib" folder from Chrome. Which I think contains the necessary files, now Where DO I PUT IT.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to dual boot ChromeOS and Ubuntu. So you seem to be running some chroot installation of Ubuntu like crouton with the ChromeOS kernel instead of the Ubuntu Linux kernel. From my point of view this combination is not supported, therefore **I'm voting to close as off-topic**.

Comment: Vote to close: Chroot installation that uses an unsupported Linux Kernel.

Comment: I did not use Crouton. I used Chrubuntu, which is booted instead of chrome, not along side. This worked very well taking less than 10 seconds to boot.

Comment: Also can anyone point me to a better community for help with my problem. I would like a answer to my question.